# JavaScript Calculators

Tags: javascript

```
var uc = 2.10;
var dort_bucuk = 1.80;
islem  = parseFloat(uc-dort_bucuk);
alert(islem) // 0.30000000000000004

var uc = 1.10;
var dort_bucuk = 0.95;
islem  = parseFloat(uc-dort_bucuk);
alert(islem) // 0.15000000000000013

var uc = 4.00;
var dort_bucuk = 3.70;
islem  = parseFloat(uc-dort_bucuk);
alert(islem)//0.2999999999999998
```

how i use like in php number_format($int,2)
why its coming 4.00-3.70 =0.2999999999999998? its must

```
<?php 
 $bir = 4.00;
 $iki = 3.70;
echo number_format($bir-$iki,2); // 0.30 
 ?>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`.toFixed(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), e.g.:

```
alert(islem.toFixed(2));
```

---

Also, note that you don't need any of the `parseFloat`s, since you are subtracting two numbers, so the result is a number.